# Can't publish Azure Function

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I have created a new Azure function which references a few of my other projects in my solution. Then I Try to publish my function to Azure by using visual studio and I get the following errors:

```
 Publish Started
  Backend.Core -> C:\Projects\Backend.Core\bin\Release\Backend.Core.dll
  Backend.EntityFramework -> C:\Projects\Backend.EntityFramework\bin\Backend.EntityFramework.dll
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(4368,5): error : The value for PublishProfile is set to 'State-Persistance-Handler - Web Deploy', expected to find the file at 'C:\Projects\Backend.EntityFramework\Properties\PublishProfiles\State-Persistance-Handler - Web Deploy.pubxml' but it could not be found. [C:\Projects\Backend.EntityFramework\Backend.EntityFramework.csproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(4375,4): error : PublishProfile(State-Persistance-Handler - Web Deploy) is set. But the $(WebPublishMethod) does not have a valid value.  Current Value is "". [C:\Projects\Backend.EntityFramework\Backend.EntityFramework.csproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(4382,5): error : Target ValidatePublishProfileSettings Failed [C:\Projects\Backend.EntityFramework\Backend.EntityFramework.csproj]
```

For some reason it looks somewhere else for the publish profile. I have no clue how this can be. Unfortunately I don't really have more information then this...

Any help is appreciated!

I am using Visual studio community 2017, Version 15.5.6

Comment: Has anyone found the actual solution to this problem? I have the same issue where I'm referencing a ASP.NET project and instead of looking for the .pubxml in the Functions project it looks for it in the ASP.NET project.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the file for the web publish profile is missing, try running through the publish setup from the start and see if that fixes your problem.

Comment: Yes. I gave up using Azure Functions. Nothing but problems. In the 2 days i have tried to use it I had 9 issues.

Comment: Publishing the Azure Function using the "Azure Publish Wizard" worked, instead of importing the profile from the Azure console.

It also used the publish settings of that source code folder, instead of c:/program files/.netstadard1.0/... ( i used netcoreapp2.1, which made it seem weird). It also uses zip deploy now, instead of "Web Deploy"

Answer (score 0):

Workarounds:

A. If there's already a `PublishProfiles` folder at the location stated in the error, remove or rename this folder.

B. Move your Azure Job `.pubxml` and `.pubxml.user` files to the folder stated in the error.

Answer (score 0):

Publishing Azure functions from Visual Studio seems very inconsistent. Some things which might help include:

1. Creating a new function and moving over the existing code.
2. Stopping the function in the Azure Portal.
3. Make sure you click on Manage Application Settings

Currently on Visual Studio Professional 2017. .Net Core 2.1 Function is using an Http Trigger.